# ob_start() without an ob_flush()

Tags: php, nusoap, output-buffering

I hired someone to write an API for me in PHP and MySQL and now have to maintain it myself. I don't know php as well as other languages.

I noticed at the start of most of the php files they have:

```
ob_start();
```

I understand that this opens a new output buffer.  The thing is that they never flush the buffer.  The code had been working fine but I've had a lot of optimization issues, slow server responses, etc.

How is it that they don't have to flush the buffer but the response is still returning?

An example would be:

```
ob_start();
include "nusoap.php";
include "config.php";
require_once "class.Database.php";
$client = new nusoap_client($config['apiURL'].'/server.php',false, false, false, false, false, 600, 600);

... process the $_GET and build a $result ...
print_r($result);
```

Obviously the `... process ...` is a wide open thing. But I'm not seeing anywhere in there that does any sort of flush or reading the ob contents.  I've also searched all the includes and don't see one in there either.

1. I checked and `implicit_flush` is set to `Off` on this server.  Since we did move this code from another server possibly on that server it was on.  But still currently this API is working on this server.
2. The reason I said "not that I can find" when someone asked if there was an ob_get_contents() is because there are include files (including nusoap.php) that include other files and while I've grepped through them and tried to trace them, I might have missed something and am still searching.  But so far it appears to my eye that no flush or get_contents is happening.

One possible answer is to say "NO, there has to either be an implicit_flush set in the php.ini file, or an implicit_flush() command somewhere, or another flush command somewhere, or getting the contents of the buffer somewhere - or the contents would never output."  To me that is what the manual suggests. But sometimes there are loopholes and PHP seems to be a language of loopholes.

***SOLVED***

Indeed I did a simple test:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    echo "Whats Up Doc!";
?>
```

and the output is seen in the browser.

Comment: `ob_get_contents`? `ob_get_clean`?

Comment: nope... not that I can find.  And I did a search in all the files for "ob_" to see what all is used.

Comment: @badweasel "not that I can find".. any IDE (or even text editor) should have a ctrl+f feature

Comment: He was using nusoap.php

Comment: ok.. i'll just rephrase to "no".  better?

Comment: @badweasel Probably you should simply have not added this to your question since it is unnecessary information anyway - however it attracts guys like me to complain.

Comment: Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) Have you enabled that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81936/discussion-between-badweasel-and-hek2mgl).

Comment: Sorry, no time for chat at the moment, I need to leave to the office. .. You can address me in the chat using @hek2mgl and I'll read it later.

Comment: I can't get in to all the business reasons of why I'm having to work on this code myself. But I don't have a choice.  I'm indie and can't afford to continue hiring out PHP. So I'm trying to understand how buffering was used in this code since it doesn't seem to match what the php manual suggests and the code is badly formatted and completely undocumented. I'll just say that the original coder didn't speak the same language as me and clearly was sloppy.

Comment: Do you have `grep`, meaning a UNIX like environment?

Comment: I'm using textmate which has a built in grep type (project search).  My server is linux.  But I'm looking through a local copy right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP ob_start() function works by catching all output to buffer and then **implicitly output this buffer on script end**.
You may execute ob_end_clean() to discard (clean) buffer.

In Your example 'print_r($result);' will send output to buffer and then PHP interpreter will send buffer to client (http server/console).

PS. Function ob_implicit_flush() has different meaning. It just flush buffer on every output call (like print or echo), and do not have effect on script finish.

Comment: So you're saying that even without any flush command or implicit flush option turned on, when it reaches the end of the php script it will output the buffer anyway?

Comment: Thanks!  So why were people asking me if I knew how to search the file?  Seems weird that I'd take such crap for asking this question seeing that it's a legit question.