# Understanding odd usage of ob_start()?

Tags: php, caching, ob-start

I found a video on utube concerning prevention of the warning:

> "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent". at
>   the following link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leIz1Q2LJr4

I looked at solutions on this site from years ago but none of them seem to work and this despite the fact that the solutions made sense.

However this utube solution which worked for me makes no sense and I was wondering if someone could explain why?

I could not open a new web page using `header('location: filename')`. I kept getting the warning. I added `ob_start()` to the beginning of my index page (the PHP section with header instruction, according to the video) and suddenly the warning went away and the page started opening. Why did this happen?

I thought `ob_start()` concerned the new page being opened and not the current active document?

I added here code below:

```
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff', false);
//stop cacheing of page
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("X-XSS-Protection: 1");
header("X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN");
```

Comment: ob_start is a 'hack' around the header issue, you shouldent need it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ob\_start() without an ob\_flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131475/ob-start-without-an-ob-flush)

Comment: The best thing to do is fix the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Simply put, the rule is: *you can't send any headers after you sent any content*. `ob_start` initializes a server side output buffer in which any content is gathered without actually sending it. That way you can echo content (which goes into the buffer), then send headers, and then 'flush' (send) the content in the buffer. That doesn't mean you strictly need it: you only need it when it's practical to generate content before sending the headers.

Comment: Unclean code needs ob_start. Sometimes I have to resort to wrapping a library include in that because the library seems to spit out random echos or prints for oddball reasons. But yeah, boils down to "you have leakage, plug it up before headers!".

Comment: I checked , I didn't have any extra ob_start() calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Cannot modify header information" error occurs if anything gets output before http headers are sent.

`ob_start()` starts a php feature called "output buffering" which will prevent php from directly outputting data (to the browser). Instead all output is "redirected" to a buffer and will only be turned into output if `ob_flush()`gets called which would in turn clear the buffer.

In your example `ob_start()` "captures" any output created before headers are sent and solves your problem. As there is no `ob_flush()` in your script all formerly create output "vanishes".